# Open "Change Your Password" window from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a windows command (sent via the command line) that open the "Change Your Password" window as shown below.

[image]

Comment: It looks like Windows 7 but it would help to know specifically which version of Windows you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

```
control userpasswords2
```

The above command will open a window with users and you can select Reset Password

[User Accounts window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEKiT.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things you can try.

[Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192806) that `control password.cpl` should work from the command line but I am not getting it in Windows 7 on a non-domain controlled computer.

Using the command `start control password.cpl` may also help.

[Here is another](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20981975/Invoke-Windows-GUI-Change-Password-dialog-box-from-command-line.html) command to try `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL password.cpl`

If those don't work, you can do it from the command line with `net user [username] [newpassword]`

Comment: None of the `password.cpl` commands work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for this.

Change the `user` variable to targeted user.

Save the file and make a shortcut of the file in startup folder.

Every line is commented on end with `;` for explanation.

## Windows Change User Password GUI.ahk

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

WindowsChangeUserPasswordGUI:
user := "Administrator"  ; user
WinGetTitle, title, A  ; Active Window Enable On Top
WinGetClass, class, A  ; Active Window Enable On Top
WinGet, exe, ProcessName, A  ; Active Window Enable On Top
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, %title% ahk_class %class% ahk_exe %exe%  ; Active Window Enable On Top
Run, netplwiz  ; User Accounts
WinWait, User Accounts ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; User Accounts
WinSet, Transparent, 0, User Accounts ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Make User Accounts Window Transparent (Not Visible)
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, %title% ahk_class %class% ahk_exe %exe%  ; Active Window Disable On Top
ControlSendRaw, SysListView321, %user%, User Accounts ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Select Specified User
ControlGet, selected, List, Selected, SysListView321, User Accounts ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Get Selected User
selected := RegExReplace(selected, "\t.*", "")  ; Get Pure User Name, Remove User Groups
ControlClick, Button6, User Accounts ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe,, Left, 1,  NA  ; Reset Password Button
WinWait, Reset Password ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Reset Password
WinSetTitle, Reset Password ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe, , Reset Password %selected%  ; Set Window Title Reset Password User
WinGetPos, passX, passY, passW, passH, Reset Password ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Get Window Position Of Reset Password 
x := (A_ScreenWidth - passW) / 2  ; Set The Coordinates For Screen Center
y := (A_ScreenHeight - passH) / 2  ; Set The Coordinates For Screen Center
WinMove, Reset Password ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe,, %x%, %y%  ; Move Reset Password Window To Screen Center
WinWaitClose, Reset Password ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Wait For Reset Password Window To Close
WinClose, User Accounts ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe netplwiz.exe  ; Close User Accounts Window
ExitApp  ; ExitApp
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no longer seeing password.cpl on any windows machine; it may be deprecated.
However, this obscure command seems to still work for launching the password dialog box:

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Hope it's useful for you.